# Why is my viewbox rendering cropped?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pdf

Here is my code. I expect the viewbox to render according to size of the pdf canvas size (which is something like 750 by 600). However, when the image is saved to pdf, the image is severely cropped. Only the top/left details are saved. I know this is the case becase if I set `page.Canvas.DrawImage`'s size parameter to various values, the image changes size, but it is always the same cropped image, so either `RenderTargetBitmap` is not rending the viewbox properly or the encoder is not encoding properly or the `pdfimage.fromstream` is not converting properly.

```
        //.. set up the doc
        var doc = new PdfDocument();
        var page = doc.Pages.Add(PdfPageSize.Letter, new PdfMargins(30f), PdfPageRotateAngle.RotateAngle0, PdfPageOrientation.Landscape);

        //.. render the viewbox (must be done or its elements don't scale)
        vb.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Height));
        vb.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Height));
        vb.UpdateLayout();
        RenderTargetBitmap render = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)vb.ActualWidth, (int)vb.ActualHeight, 150, 150, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        render.Render(vb);

        //.. save the render to memory
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(render);
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
        encoder.Save(stream);

        //.. use spire pdf to convert the stream to an image
        var img = PdfImage.FromStream(stream);
        float widthFitRate = img.PhysicalDimension.Width / page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width;
        float heightFitRate = img.PhysicalDimension.Height / page.Canvas.ClientSize.Height;
        float fitRate = Math.Max(widthFitRate, heightFitRate);
        float fitWidth = img.PhysicalDimension.Width / fitRate;
        float fitHeight = img.PhysicalDimension.Height / fitRate;
        page.Canvas.DrawImage(img, new PointF(0,0), new SizeF(img.PhysicalDimension.Width, img.PhysicalDimension.Height  ));
        doc.SaveToFile(@"C:\test.pdf");
        doc.Close();
```

Comment: I've never tried drawing to a `RenderTargetBitmap` at anything other than 96dpi.  Have you tried changing your DPI values to see if that affects the cropping?  You may need to adjust the `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` if the visual you're drawing was originally rendered at 96dpi, e.g., multiply each by `150d/96d`.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. The image is no longer cropped. Thank you!